# Actual memory impact of adding an item to a collection

Tags: java

When I put a 2MB object `Foo bar` into `Collection<Foo>`, are there now 4MB of `Foo`s in memory or only 2MB?

e.g.

```
Foo twoMBObject = new Foo();
ArrayList<Foo> bax = new ArrayList<>();
bax.add(twoMBObject);

/* Do we now have bax-twoMBObject & twoMBObject or just twoMBObject 
and a pointer to twoMBObject in the list? */
```

**Edit**
I'm having a hard time figuring out if the suggested duplicate question is actually a duplicate. Although the accepted answer does not answer this question, one of the answers provided does. I'm not sure how to proceed here.

Comment: collection contains reference to object. so 2 Mb in memory

Comment: don't worry, it's just 2 mb. you add a reference to a list, not a cloned object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does appending/removing entries to a Java list reallocate memory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34617193/does-appending-removing-entries-to-a-java-list-reallocate-memory)

Comment: @Raedwald I think *your* answer to that question is an acceptable answer for this question, but the accepted is not. And I honestly can't tell if the question is actually a duplicate of my question.

Comment: @nukeforum Ignore whether a particular answer is marked as "accepted": that just indicates that the poster of the question thought that it was the best answer. It has no bearing on whether two questions are duplicates.

Comment: @Raedwald As I mentioned, I'm not seeing how my question and the one linked are duplicates. Maybe I should just make a meta post?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2MB because you just add a reference to the object and do not create a copy of the object.

An easy way to test this is by using the `Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()` method. Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Byte[] b = new Byte[1000];
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

    long allocatedMemory = runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory();
    System.out.println(allocatedMemory);

    List<Byte[]> collection = new ArrayList<>();
    collection.add(b);

    allocatedMemory = runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory();
    System.out.println(allocatedMemory);
}
```

Comment: I just looked at the doc. It is. Thanks for the correction:

Comment: I'll accept this one as soon as I find out whether this is a duplicate question or not.

Answer (score 2):

> are there now 4MB of Foos in memory or only 2MB?

2 MB, because when you do `new Foo()`, 2MB of space is allocated and a reference to the object is returned. Now when you `bax.add(twoMBObject);` you are essentially adding the reference to the ArrayList and not creating a "new" object.

If you try to change something in the object using the reference `twoMBObject` you will see the change reflected in the object added to the `ArrayList` as well. This proves that its the same object.